# How to solve the problem that Kafka cannot connect remotely？

Tags: apache-kafka

I think this problem is caused by server.properties file advertise listener,but I can't set it in kafka operator.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately you've not provided any information for us to help solve your issue. Please add more details, such as information about your environment, the `server.properties` file, etc

Comment: # The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#    listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#  EXAMPLE:
#  listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#  listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
# advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

Comment: The environment is use kafka operator deploy kafka!

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of sharing details via comment. Be sure to include as much relevant data as possible. Just saying you have a problem is not enough, show us the error, show us what you've done. Otherwise we can't magically guess the answer!

Comment: A k8s "operator" should set these values for you correctly, or at least via k8s configs, not directly editing any files within the pods

Comment: error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic flume not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Comment: I try to edit kafka-persistent.yaml file, and Added the following configuration： environment:KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://x.x.x.x:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

Comment: @ OneCricketeer.  Yes, I think so,but I can‘t find these values in kafka operator documentation.